# Having trouble implementing my deck and hand classes

Tags: java, oop

I'm still rather new to programming, so here goes, I have created a Cards and Deck class which work great, but the Hand class is where I run into trouble. In the driver I have to ask the user, how many players there are going to be as well as how many cards in the hand. Here's what I have so far, I'll try to post only the necessary code to keep it short.

Here's my Deck Class:

```
public class Deck 
{

    private Cards [] deck;
    private int nextCard;


    public Deck()
    {
        deck = new Cards[52];
        int iCardCount=0;   // Holds how many cards have been created.
        for ( int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++ ) 
        {
            for ( int face = 1; face <= 13; face++ ) 
            {
                deck[iCardCount] = new Cards(iCardCount);
                iCardCount++;
            }
        }
        nextCard = 0;
    }


    public void shuffle ()
    {


        for ( int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) 
        {
            Random ran = new Random();
            int iRand = ran.nextInt(52);
            Cards temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[iRand];
            deck[iRand] = temp;
        }
        nextCard = 0;
    }


    public Cards dealACard ()
    {
        if (nextCard < 52)
        {
            System.out.println( deck[nextCard++]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("\nError, out of cards." );

        }
        return (null);
    }

    public Hand dealAHand (int n)
    {   
        Hand deal = new Hand();
        String sHand = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            sHand += "" + dealACard();
        }
        return deal;
    }   

}
```

For the dealAHand method, my instructor had us using returning a String before, but now that we've created a Hand class she made us change the String to Hand which has thrown me for a loop.

Here's my Hand class:

```
public class Hand 
{
    private int handSize;           //how many cards in the hand
    private int cardsInHand;        //counter
    private Cards [] hand;

    public Hand ()
    {
        hand = new Cards[];
        handSize = 5;
        cardsInHand = 0;
    }

    public Hand (int handSize)
    {
        hand = new Cards [handSize];
        this.handSize = handSize;
    }

    public void addCard (Cards card)
    {
        if (cardsInHand >= handSize) 
        {
            Cards[] temp = new Cards[hand.length*2];
            for (int i=0; i < cardsInHand; i++)
            {   
                temp[i] = hand[i];
                hand = temp;
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem I have is when asking the user how many players will be playing, do I create a new object for hand? like `Hand player1 = new Hand ();` ? what if they input 5 players?

Also, when I ask for how many cards are in a hand, and they input 15 cards a hand if there are to be 3 players? I know I will be needing to use a `Do While` loop, but would that be done in the `Hand` class or in my driver?

I know this it's rather long, but a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The job of the Hand class is to keep track of x number of Card objects (yes, please change your Cards class to Card to follow Java conventions). Hand neither knows nor cares about what game it's playing -- it's simply a container. Also, you have bigger problems ahead: you don't seem to be using your suit or face variables when you're building your Deck.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Am I not using it in my default constructor? `deck = new Card[52];
        for ( int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++ ) 
        {
            for ( int face = 1; face <= 13; face++ ) 
            {
                deck[iCardCount] = new Card(iCardCount);
                iCardCount++;
            }`

Answer (score 2):

Use the **object** in object-oriented to help you.

Is a card an object? Yes, and so you have a **Card** object.

Is a hand an object? Yes (You have to think somewhere between concrete and abstract.) So you have a **Hand** object.

What about if you have multiple hands?
Think about where you might put multiple **int** values or multiple **Integer** values. Would a player be an object?

Do you want the driver to iterate through the Card's in a hand directly?
If not, how would that work? What would you need Hand to do to allow the driver to iterate through the cards?

Keep in mind object-oriented principles: encapsulation, etc.

Comment: I agree with most of your points, but you are asking too many questions, it's rather confusing, you can also add some code snippets explaining your idea.

Comment: @wdb So, if I had multiple hands I would call the `Hand` class with the **int** as the parameter and pass the user inputted **int** variable through there correct?

Comment: In the version of the Hand constructor that has an int parameter, look at what the int parameter is used for.Does it determine the number of Hands? If not, how could you get multiple hands? Keep in mind that there are several levels to this scenario. You have a

Comment: Sorry. It timed out on me. The point is that the different levels may have different ways of getting multiple objects (like Hand's or Card's).

Answer (score 1):

Remember, Java is an OBJECT ORIENTED programming language.  Think of your classes like they are real world objects.  Your `Deck` contains a number of `Cards`  A `Hand` belongs to a `Player`, and contains a certain number of `Cards`.  And what are you playing? A `Game`.  So, picture it like this:

You're playing a `Game`:

```
public class Game {

}
```

How many players are in your game?  Whatever the answer, create that many `Players`:

```
public class Game {

    public Player[] players;

    public Game(int numPlayers) {
        players = new Player[numPlayers];
    }

}
```

Each player...

```
public class Player {

}
```

... has a hand:

```
public class Player {
    public Hand hand;
}
```

Each hand is made up of some `Cards`:

```
public class Hand {
    public Card[] cards;
}
```

How many cards will there be in a hand?  Set the value when you create the Game:

```
public class Game {

    public Player[] players;
    public static int numCardsPerHand; // static, unless you have multiple games going at the same time

    public Game(int numPlayers, int numCardsPerHand) {
        players = new Player[numPlayers];
        this.numCardsPerHand = numCardsPerHand
    }

}
```

... and use that value when you create your hands:

```
public class Hand {
    public Card[] cards;

    public Hand() {
        cards = new Card[Game.numCardsPerHand];// alternatively, pass this value in the ctor.
    }
}
```

... and so on.  Also think about how "actions" get performed.  For instance, in my mind, if you were to create an `AddCardToHand(newCard)` method in the Hand class, then that means the hand passively/magically has a new card.  However, if you were to put that method in the Player class, then that means to me that the player is actively putting a new card in their hand, rather than it just !poof! appearing.

Note that in the above example, there's no real need to differentiate between `Players` and `Hands`.  They essentially are the same thing.  Now, if you had more properties on the `Player` (for instance, male/female, how many times they've played the game, score, etc.) then you would need the separate class.  Here, though, I think you can combine them.

When you `deal()`, iterate through your players' hands and assign cards to the slots in the array (the `Card[]` array in the `Hand` class).

**tldr:** OO (object oriented) programming's beauty is that it mimics real-world objects.  Try to think how your game would be played in real life, what objects (cards, deck, players, etc.) would be involved.  Remember your restraint checking.  For instance, a normal deck only has 52 cards.  If that's the case for your scenario, you can't deal 5 cards to 15 people!

From what I've seen so far, it looks like you started out ok, and then just got so wrapped up in things you got yourself a little lost.  Remember, sometimes it's good to step back and look at things from a different angle.  Try diagramming it on a chalkboard/whiteboard (don't use sharpie).

You're on the right track.  Good luck.